# How can one input 圏点 (emphasis marks)?

Tags: discussion, formatting

I understand that [圏点【けんてん】](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%9C%8F%E7%82%B9) are not very often used in Japanese writing as much as *italics* are used in English, but how do you add 圏点【けんてん】 using an English keyboard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably not what you were asking, but as an additional note, you can add 圏点 on this site using the furigana syntax:

> [圏点]​{﹅﹅}

turns into

> [圏点]{﹅﹅}

And one can get that character by kanji completing けんてん in most IDEs.

Note that you do need the [] around the thing you are trying to put furigana on.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why exactly you want to use a keyboard to add them, because emphasis marks, like italics in English, are not part of the text but of the formatting/typesetting.

However, common Office Software supports adding emphasis marks through their text formatting tools:

### Microsoft Word

You can add emphasis marks through the `Format > Font` dialog. (I'm sorry for posting a screenshot in a German language version of Office, but it's the only one I had available at the moment)
[image: Emphasis marks in Microsoft Word]

### LibreOffice Writer

You can add emphasis marks through the `Format > Character` dialog. You have to enable East Asian Language support through the options first if you use the English language version.
[image: Emphasis marks in LibreOffice Writer]